# c# Outlook add-in custom Icons with custom Region Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook 2010 addin in Visual Studio 2010.

I have created a custom Form Region that is going to implement the messageClass called:

> IPM.Note.Archivado

This class is going to be assigned to processed messages by an application using exchange
web services that will run nightly. This is tested and working ok. When the Form Region
is loading I can recover the:

> message.MessageClass as "IPM.Note.Archivado"

Ok, What I need now, It's to assign a different inbox icon to the messages that matches
that messageClass, so I used the property panel in the custom Region Form and selected
icons for read, forwared, default, actions without problem.

I can achieve this if I choose the FormRegionType as **replacement** or **Replace-ALL** in the
manifest, but what I need is this form windows to be **AdJoining.**

When the formRegionType is **adjoining** I can not get the assigned icons to load in the
inbox panel.

I have been reading a lot of documentation but I can't find the solution to my problem.

Here it's form Region definition:

```
 [Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClassAttribute.Note)]
        [Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass("IPM.Note.Archivado")]
        [Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionName("hnaOutlookAddin.FormRegionMessageClassArchivado")]
        public partial class FormRegionMessageClassArchivadoFactory
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **custom Outlook icons** - you must use a [replacement form region](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11121393/175679). If you need an *adjoining form region* - you need to create another class. You can have multiple form regions targeting the same message class. I've used both replacement and adjoining form regions for `IPM.Note.XXXX`.

Comment: Using replacement form region, makes the mail preview to show a blank page instead of the mail, is there a workaround ? Something like make the form region inherit the base one ?